# Performance issues in CP with +60k articles database

Tags: entries, control-panel, performance

We are are working with a large dataset of over 60k articles. The craft control panel has a very hard time loading the entries list tables. Using debug I see that the queries that takes up the longest (+10s) is the one that starts likes this "SELECT sourceId AS source, targetId AS target" . Does anyone has any ideas or tips on how we can get around/fix this issue?

This is an image form the debugger on the ajax call loading a list of entries in the contents tab.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Doing further research i noticed the performance impact is mainly due to sorting on the default publication date. When sorting on the title field all the performance issues are gone.